# How to set text widget under sized box in a container flutter

Tags: flutter

In flutter how to set a text widget under a sized box in a container as below? I tried but didn't get what I wanted. Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLRje.jpg,
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfMa8.jpg

[What I want][1]

[What I get][2]

```
Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Color(0xffb2b2b2),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 70.0,
                    height: 70.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Color(0xffe31da8),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.notifications,
                            size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    )),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 30),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text('Language',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              letterSpacing: 0.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Color(0xff5f2dea),
                              decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add multiple widget vertically you have to use Column. Row is used to multiple widget in one line (Horizontally). 1. Remove unnecessary use of Row from your code. Use padding, margin or alignment parameters to give proper spacing or alignment. Here is updated code:

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Color(0xffb2b2b2),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: 120.0,
                  height: 120.0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        color: Color(0xffe31da8),
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications,
                              size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: const Text('Language',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xff5f2dea),
                                decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
```